# Are dictionaries supported in epub 3.1?

Tags: epub, epub-reader

Are dictionaries, as described here:

http://www.idpf.org/epub/dict/

covered in epub 3.1?

Which readers support them? Are there any working examples of epub documents using dictionaries?

Answer (score 2):

> Are dictionaries, as described here [...]

The dictionaries and glossaries specification is not a part of the epub3.x standards.

> Which readers support them?

None that I know of.

> Are there any working examples of epub documents using dictionaries?

No.

If you want to use dictionaries, you'll have to create StarDict dicionaries, which are supported by most Android devices, but not by iOS devices. (There are iOS StarDict dictionary apps, but you can't use them as lookup dictionaries in iOS ebook apps because of iOS limitations.)

If the dictionary is rather small, you could theoretically embed it as an Sqlite database in epub3 books and query it with JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks! The dictionary is small and I can query it with javascript. Should I capture onclick events on the words and display my own modal box using css and html5? If not, how should I do the presentation? Will it be possible to have this behave in a consistent manner across readers and is this recommended with regard to epub3? Finally, are there any examples of epub documents using onclick events on words and presenting popup modals? - excluding those achieved using popup footnotes.